# Mule SMTP not connecting due to password contains special character

Tags: smtp, gmail, mule, anypoint-studio

I need to connect to a gmail account to send an email using the SMTP component in Mule.

The password for the account contains the @ sign and it throws the error shown below.  How can I resolve this without changing the password?  The account was set up by the test team so I'm not the owner of the email account so unable to change.

Error message (password changed):

```
2016-10-12 15:43:47,827 ERROR Attempted to append to non-started appender Forced-Console
ERROR 2016-10-12 15:43:47,813 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: smtp://test:"Password@1"@smtp.gmail.com:25
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3186) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
```

Thanks

Comment: What Mule version are you using?

Comment: Also, have you tried setting the "@" encoded? It would be "%40" I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `@` to `%40` as mentioned by afelisatti in comments worked.